# change class of div on anchor click. how to implement with classie.js?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am using the following jquery code to hide/show a mobile popup menu.

```
( function( window ) {
'use strict';
// class helper functions from bonzo https://github.com/ded/bonzo

function classReg( className ) {
return new RegExp("(^|\\s+)" + className + "(\\s+|$)"); }


// classList support for class management 
// altho to be fair, the api sucks because it won't accept multiple classes at once var hasClass, addClass, removeClass;

if ( 'classList' in document.documentElement ) {
hasClass = function( elem, c ) {
    return elem.classList.contains( c );
 }; 

 addClass = function( elem, c ) {
    elem.classList.add( c );
};   

  removeClass = function( elem, c ) {
   elem.classList.remove( c );
   };
}

else {   hasClass = function( elem, c ) {
    return classReg( c ).test( elem.className );
 };

addClass = function( elem, c ) {
    if ( !hasClass( elem, c ) ) {
      elem.className = elem.className + ' ' + c;
    }   };   removeClass = function( elem, c ) {
    elem.className = elem.className.replace( classReg( c ), ' ' );
   }; }

function toggleClass( elem, c ) {   var fn = hasClass( elem, c ) ? removeClass : addClass;   fn( elem, c ); }

var classie = {
// full names
hasClass: hasClass,
addClass: addClass,
removeClass: removeClass,
toggleClass: toggleClass,
// short names
has: hasClass,
add: addClass,
remove: removeClass,
toggle: toggleClass };

// transport if ( typeof define === 'function' && define.amd ) {   // AMD   define( classie ); } else {   // browser global   window.classie
= classie; }

})( window );

(function() {
var triggerBttn = document.getElementById( 'trigger-overlay' ),                                     overlay = document.querySelector( 'div.overlay' ),
closeBttn = overlay.querySelector( 'button.overlay-close' );            transEndEventNames = {
 'WebkitTransition': 'webkitTransitionEnd',
'MozTransition': 'transitionend', 
'OTransition': 'oTransitionEnd',
'msTransition': 'MSTransitionEnd',
'transition': 'transitionend'
 },         
 transEndEventName = transEndEventNames[ Modernizr.prefixed( 'transition' ) ],
    support = { transitions : Modernizr.csstransitions };

    function toggleOverlay() {
    if( classie.has( overlay, 'open' ) ) {
        classie.remove( overlay, 'open' );
        classie.add( overlay, 'close' ); 
        var onEndTransitionFn = function( ev ) {
                if( support.transitions ) {
                    if( ev.propertyName !== 'visibility' ) return;
                    this.removeEventListener( transEndEventName,     onEndTransitionFn );
                }
                classie.remove( overlay, 'close' );
        };          
if( support.transitions ) {
 overlay.addEventListener( transEndEventName, onEndTransitionFn );                   }          
 else {
 onEndTransitionFn();           }       }       else if( !classie.has( overlay, 'close' ) ) {           classie.add( overlay, 'open' );         }   }

    triggerBttn.addEventListener( 'click', toggleOverlay );     closeBttn.addEventListener( 'click', toggleOverlay ); })();
    $("a").click(function(){
       if( !classie.has( overlay, 'close' ) ) {
      classie.add( overlay, 'open' );
    }
    });
```

I'm trying to write a function that will change the class of div.overlay from 'open' to 'close' when an anchor within the div.overlay is clicked.

I tried this, but there's definitely some syntax and logical errors. also not sure where to put it in the function.

> $("a").click(function(){
>              if( !classie.has( overlay, 'close' ) ) {
>             classie.add( overlay, 'open' );
>           }
>           });

Can someone help me write the function to achieve the change class to 'close' on anchor click, and instruct me on where to put it?

I tried to implement an answer, but to no avail. maybe looking at my html code will help. how specific do my selectors need to be?
thanks.

```
             <p><button id="trigger-overlay" class="whitetext smalltext quickfade" type="button">MENU</button></p>
      <div class="overlay overlay-scale">
      <button type="button" class="overlay-close fade">Close</button>
      <div class="info">
        <div id="hamdiv">
          <a id="hammenu" class="blacktext quickfade" href="home.html#graybox.html">ABOUT</a>
          <a id="hammenu" class="blacktext quickfade" href="work.html">WORK</a>
          <a id="hammenu" class="blacktext quickfade" href="home.html#footer">CONTACT</a>
        </div>
      </div>
  </div>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First of all, your selector should not be just `"a"` but instead `"div.overlay a"` because you said you want to listen to `<a>` clicks inside `div.overlay`.

Secondly, you can use jQuery for the class changing part and also to verify if `"div.overlay"` has the class `close` toggled or not.

```
$("div.overlay a").click(function () {
  if (!$("div.overlay").hasClass("close")) {
    $("div.overlay").addClass("open");
    //$("div.overlay").removeClass("close");
  }
});
```

I also added a `removeClass("close")` call because you probably want it, but wether you need that bit of logic or not is your call.

Finally, regarding where you place this code, it could just be on top level (leftmost level) because it's just an event listener.

Comment: Thanks for the help. I had to change the scope of the click function to get it to work, but it works well now. Have a good one.